# Python: How to go to a link and open it if it exists

Tags: python, hyperlink

I found this code:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://eample.com')
```

How do I modify it so that it will only open the link if the return code is 200?

Comment: Possible design flaw: Not only 200 OK means success. There is also codes like 202 accepted, etc... [the list](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is long and after all, the browser already adds the utility to check if the page can be displayed. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Won't everything be 200 status because of failed URI search assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `requests` package to send a `HEAD` request to the desired location and then create an `if`

```
if requests.head(url).status_code == 200: webbrowser.open(url) # open url if status is 200
```

Comment: you should propably use `HEAD` instead of `GET` to request the page since you don't use the body, anyway. See [requests.head](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.0/api/#requests.head)